# In a 3-dimensional graph, can the transparency of edges be controlled by an array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, networkx

#### Abstract

I learned that in 2-dimensional graphs, arrays can be used to control the transparency of edges and nodes. I wanted to apply this to 3D graphs as well, so I asked the question.

Here is the source code I tried.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

def draw_graph(edges):
    G = nx.Graph()
    G.add_edges_from(edges)
    pos = nx.spring_layout(G , dim = 3)
    pos_ary = np.array([pos[n] for n in G])

    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (20,10) , facecolor = "w")
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111 , projection = "3d")

    ax.scatter(
        pos_ary[:, 0],
        pos_ary[:, 1],
        pos_ary[:, 2],
        s = 200,
        )
    
    alphas = [0.1 , 0.2 , 0.3 , 0.4 , 0.5 , 0.6 , 0.7 , 0.8 , 0.9 , 1]

    for e in G.edges:
        node0_pos = pos[e[0]]
        node1_pos = pos[e[1]]
        xx = [node0_pos[0] , node1_pos[0]]
        yy = [node0_pos[1] , node1_pos[1]]
        zz = [node0_pos[2] , node1_pos[2]]
        ax.draw_networkx_nodes(xx , yy , zz , color = "b" , alpha = alphas)
    plt.show()

edges = [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 0), (0, 5), (1, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (4, 9)]
draw_graph(edges)
```

The following error statement was output for such source code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Program Files/Python36/3d.py", line 35, in <module>
    draw_graph(edges)
  File "C:/Program Files/Python36/3d.py", line 30, in draw_graph
    ax.draw_networkx_nodes(xx , yy , zz , color = "b" , alpha = alphas)
AttributeError: 'Axes3DSubplot' object has no attribute 'draw_networkx_nodes'
```

I have an think that the error is probably due to the use of a syntax that does not exist in the library `Axes3DSubplot`.
Are there any desirable libraries?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired output like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

def draw_graph(edges):
    G = nx.Graph()
    G.add_edges_from(edges)
    pos = nx.spring_layout(G , dim = 3)
    pos_ary = np.array([pos[n] for n in G])

    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (20,10) , facecolor = "w")
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111 , projection = "3d")

    ax.scatter(
        pos_ary[:, 0],
        pos_ary[:, 1],
        pos_ary[:, 2],
        s = 200,
        )
    
    alphas = [0.1 , 0.2 , 0.3 , 0.4 , 0.5 , 0.6 , 0.7 , 0.8 , 0.9 , 1]

    for i, e in enumerate(G.edges):
        node0_pos = pos[e[0]]
        node1_pos = pos[e[1]]



        xx = [node0_pos[0] , node1_pos[0]]
        yy = [node0_pos[1] , node1_pos[1]]
        zz = [node0_pos[2] , node1_pos[2]]
        ax.plot(xx , yy , zz , color = "b", alpha = alphas[i] )
    plt.show()

edges = [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 0), (0, 5), (1, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (4, 9)]
draw_graph(edges)
```

[image]

You could also pass it as an array if you would create a list of the Line2D object and then apply it to them...